# ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROW not working

Tags: sql, db2, global-temp-tables

I want to load a data in temp table in DB2. in syntax when i use ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS compiler throws an error:

> Lookup Error - DB2 Database Error: ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "ON" was found following "P BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER)".  Expected tokens may include:  "".

When I replaced On commit preserve rows by **definition only** temp table is successfully created but I don't see my sub query data inserted in the temp table. Can you please help me where I am making mistake?

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TEMP_TABLE AS 
(SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, NET_AMOUNT
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME WHERE 1=1 AND COLUMN1='a') ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Comment: The correct statement syntax can be found [in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003272.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-7-123&lang=en). It is not possible to declare a temporary table and insert data into it with one statement.

Comment: @mustaccio - Not on the LUW version, at least (you can on the iSeries, but that's not going to help him here).

Comment: Thanks mustaccio.. I created and inserted in two different comands. Worked fine wih commit on preserv rows. Thank you